# Sinatra cache control is not working

Tags: ruby, caching, sinatra, sinatra-assetpack

This is what I have done to my server

```
set :static_cache_control, [:public, {:max_age => 604800}]
```

However, when I use firebug I still see 0 max-age. And I'm using Sinatra Assets Pack http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/

I'm not sure if they conflict each other?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which file you add max-age header?
If it's JavaScript or CSS file, please try to build files with Sinatra-assetpack.
Files built are located in under 'public' directory.
Please see the following, written how to build.
http://ricostacruz.com/sinatra-assetpack/#need_to_build_the_files